# Identifying the two three digit numbers from a set of single digit numbers

Tags: number-theory

I know the two numbers have to start with 7 & 6 respectively and end with 2 or 3 (though I don't know which of these two numbers will go to the number with 7 and 6). That leaves with 4 and 5 as the middle number.

Is **"Trial and Error"** the only way to figure out the answer to this problem or is there a **"Method"** to solve this problem.

Any help will be greatly appreciated since I have to teach this to my 3rd grader son.

**Question:
Two three-digit numbers are made of 2,3,4,5,6 and 7. Their product is the largest that is possible. What are these two numbers?**

Comment: $777$ and $777$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the "hundreds product" to be as large as possible, so you start off with:

- $7ab\times6cd$

You want the "tens product" to be as large as possible, so you continue with either one of:

- $75b\times64d$
- $74b\times65d$

You want the "ones product" to be as large as possible, so you end up with either one of:

- $753\times642$
- $752\times643$
- $743\times652$
- $742\times653$

---

Then, you explain to your 3rd grader son:

- The **sum** of each pair of numbers in the list above is equal ($1395$)
- Therefore, the closer they are to each other, the higher their product is

So you simply choose the last option in that list, which is $742\times653=484526$.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to convey.

Of the 4 choices of "Number Pairs", the ones with the least difference will give the maximum value (Highest Product). 

So,in this case (742-653 = 89) where as the other three have differences greater than 89.

Thanks,
Rajee 

The sum of each pair of numbers in the list above is equal (1395)
Therefore, the closer they are to each other, the higher their product is

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you can only use each number once.

Lets suppose, just for a moment, that maybe you could use the midpoints.

and remember that $742 = 7\cdot 100 + 4\cdot 10 + 2$

$7\cdot 100 + 4.5\cdot 10 +2.5 = 747.5$
$6\cdot 100 + 4.5\cdot 10 +2.5 = 647.5$

Now, we need to click one of those number up by 5 and the other down by 5, because we can't use the midpoint.

$(747.5 + 5)(674.5 - 5) < (747.5 - 5)(674.5 + 5)$  Multiply it out if it isn't obvious.

Clicking up the smaller number has more power, because the amount you click it up is multiplied by a bigger number.

$(742)(653)$ is your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is basically just the [Greedy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm). You want to assign a place to the digits starting with the largest digit and work down to the smallest digit. If you take any two digits then 7*6 gives the biggest value. So those two values go in the two hundreds places. 
unknown 1 = 7??
unknown 2 = 6??

Now is 5*60 bigger or is 5*70 bigger? So the 5 is the tenths digit with the second unknown, not the first unknown.
 
unknown 1 = 7??
unknown 2 = 65?

Now for the first unknown pick 4 to go into the hundredths digit.
unknown 1 = 74?
unknown 2 = 65?

Then using same logic
unknown 1 = 74?
unknown 2 = 653

and finally
unknown 1 = 742
unknown 2 = 653

Comment: "5*7 is bigger than 5*6, so the 5 is the hundredths digit with the second value" - why???

Comment: @barakmanos - Which is larger 750*600=450000 or 700*650=455000 ?

Comment: First of all, you wrote $5*6$ vs $5*7$, not $750*600$ vs $700*650$, so I don't quite see the relation. Second, the $0$ digit is not "part of the game" here, so I don't think that you can use it as part of your method in order to determine the answer.

Comment: @barakmanos - Ok, I rewrote the answer a bit. But it is the Greedy algorithm.